# How to calculate expected for Wiener process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, expected-value

I had some homework exercises from stochastic processes and have some difficult with expression.

So, I need to compute $\mathbb{E}\left[\left(X_1 + 2X_2 + 3X_3\right)^2\right]$,  where $X_t$ is a Wiener process.

[Updated]

What I had do:
 1. Set $D_2$ = $X_2$ - $X_1$, then $D_3$ = $X_3$ - $X_2$

2. Calculate:

$$
\begin{split}
\mathbb{E}\left[\left(X_1 + 2X_2 + 3X_3\right)^2\right]
 &= \mathbb{E}\left[\left(X_1 + 2(X_1+D_2) + 3(X_2 + D_3)\right)^2\right]\\
 &= \mathbb{E}\left[\left(3X_1 + 2D_2 + 3X_2 + 3D_3\right)^2\right] \\
 &= ... ?
\end{split}
$$

3. Stop on this, should I expand binomial coefficient next?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! You will get more meaningful responses and less downvotes if you exhibit some work on the problem and explain the context in which you encountered it (self-learning, homework, research, etc.) Using MAthJax also helps a good bit.

Comment: @gt6989b updated review with your suggestions, thank you

Comment: +1, Either let $Y = X_1+2X_2$ and you completed the needed piece from my example below and now compute $\mathbb{E}[(Y+3X_3)^2]$. Alternatively, expand the original expression first and make the substitution into $D_i$ when you have to compute $\mathbb{E}[X_iX_j]$.

Comment: Another point, completely missed it -- expand $X_2 = X_1 + D_2$ and you get 3 terms, not 4

Comment: @gt6989b Could you explain, what you mean with  expand the original expression first and make the substitution into $D_i$ ?

Comment: Please see the update to my answer below

Answer (score 1):

Let's do a simpler example. Let $D_2 = X_2 - X_1$, then $D_2$ and $X_1$ are independent because of independent increments property of the Wiener process.

You have
$$
\begin{split}
\mathbb{E}\left[\left(X_1 + 2X_2\right)^2\right]
 &= \mathbb{E}\left[\left(X_1 + 2(X_1+D_2)\right)^2\right] \\
 &= \mathbb{E}\left[\left(3X_1 + 2D_2\right)^2\right] \\
 &= \mathbb{E}\left[9X_1^2 + 4D_2^2+12X_1D_2\right] \\
 &= 9 \mathbb{E}\left[X_1^2\right]
  + 4 \mathbb{E}\left[D_2^2\right]
  + 12 \mathbb{E}[X_1 D_2] \\
 &= 9 \mathbb{E}\left[X_1^2\right]
  + 4 \mathbb{E}\left[D_2^2\right]
  + 12 \mathbb{E}[X_1] \cdot \mathbb{E}[D_2] 
\end{split}
$$
where the last step is due to independence of $X_1$ and $D_2$.

Can you finish the example and apply to your problem?

---

The alternative approach is to first expand
$$
\begin{split}
\mathbb{E}\left[\left(X_1 + 2X_2 + 3X_3\right)^2\right]
 &= \mathbb{E}\left[X_1^2\right] + 4\mathbb{E}\left[X_2^2\right]
                                 + 9\mathbb{E}\left[X_3^2\right]\\
 &+ 2 \mathbb{E}[X_1 \cdot 2X_2] + 2 \mathbb{E}[X_1 \cdot 3X_3]
 + 2 \mathbb{E}[2X_2 \cdot 2X_3] 
\end{split}
$$
and then make the substitutions $X_2 = X_1 + D_2$ and $X_3 = X_1 + D_2 + D_3$.

Comment: thank you, I will try. And let you know

Comment: @DimaChuvardinsky looking fwd, please do